# Can't Read Data from CSV file to R Markdown Shiny Document

Tags: r, markdown, shiny

I am experimenting with the R Markdown Shiny documents for interactive reporting. First trouble got is to read data from local csv file.

`{r, cache=TRUE}
raw1<-read.csv("data/set1.csv")
splits <- unique(raw1$split)`

The error message I have is " Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection".

There is no issue to use the above code to read data in regular R Markdown documents. Can anyone help the best practice to create interactive reporting using Shiny Document?

Comment: That error often means that R couldn't find the file. Might have to do with the working directory.  Do a `cat(ls())` or `cat(wd())` or something similar just before trying to read the file so that you know where you are.

Comment: In a shiny application you need to put the .csv in the same directory as your `ui.r` and `server.r` files, or in a subdirectory under them. Not sure if that is the same in your case.

Comment: Put the full path in. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing cache to FALSE. I haven't been able to successfully use caching when hosting on a Shiny server.

Answer (score 0):

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(data.table)
dataset <- fread("yourfile.csv",header=T)
```
````

Try fread from data.table. It should help. Worked well for me. It's also way faster than read.csv.